# Why is one maven project imported into Eclipse unable to see JUnit or Mockito artifacts?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 2019-03 with Java 8 on Win7, with m2e installed.

I have a bunch of projects all built with Maven, that present SpringBoot REST services in different subdomains.  All of them build fine from the command line, and all but one have no compile issues in Eclipse.

I just inherited responsibility for a new project which has already been running, but which was maintained by a separate team.  All the projects were constructed from a template, so many things are the same as I expect.  It builds fine from the command line with Maven, including all the unit tests.

When I import the project from my local git repo, it consistently reports that it can't find the "Junit" or "Mockito" artifacts, which causes compile errors in all of the unit tests.  Those artifacts clearly show up in the effective POM, and in the "Maven Dependencies" tree in the Package Explorer. There are no red marks in the pom.xml.

I've tried "Update Project".  I've tried deleting the project and reimporting.

I've looked at the entire set of compile errors, and there's nothing else unusual, besides not being able to find these artifacts.

I've compared this project with a similar project that doesn't have this symptom, including the .classpath and .project files.  There are very minor differences, but I haven't seen any differences that seem like they might be significant.

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Clone the project grom git without using eclipse, delete .classpath, .project and .settings. Then import the project as Maven project. Wait for sometime and then press Alt+F5. Try to check this.

Comment: Good strategy.  No effect, however.

Comment: I've resolved this problem.  I didn't know someone else was pushing broken code into this project.  The behavior I saw was just due to timing.